# Generate C# proxy call from wsdl + xsd

Tags: c#, web-services, proxy, xsd, wsdl

Hi i need generate web service proxy for C# client. Web service is java. I have wsdl + xsd file for web service.

I try use wsdl.exe tool

wsdl /out:D:\filename.cs /protocol:SOAP12 C:\filename.wsdl

But problem is that some definition are in xsd file. how to merge it. I think it is new standard

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [/par switch](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaevans/archive/2005/11/22/496067.aspx) for the WSDL tool

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been a while since this question was asked, but I also needed to use an XSD with my WSDL today, so this popped up in my search.

I ended up using `wsdl.exe` like this:

```
wsdl C:\filename.wsdl C:\filename.xsd /out:C:\filename.cs /protocol:SOAP12
```

If nothing else, it might be useful to someone else someday :-)